# making android espresso tests run based on environment it is running in

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, environment-variables, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have espresso tests which run fine. the only problem is that I have two environments e.g. local and staging. when running espresso tests on the local environment I don't want some functions to execute. but when on staging environment I want all functions to be executed.

I tried using windows environment variable in the espresso test code i.e. `system.getenv()` but it is not working, as the test code runs inside android emulator/device which does not have access to windows environment variable.

I need some variable or way to make espresso tests aware of the environment it is running in either through Gradle or some other way.

Answer (score 3):

I researched and found the solution to the above problem that i asked.

One need to add following under build.gradle:

```
buildTypes a {
            buildConfigField "String", "currentEnvironment", System.getenv("TEST_ENVIRONMENT").toString();
        }
```

This will declate and set the variable in BuildConfig.java file as `public static final String currentEnvironment = "local";`

Then the currentEnvironment can be imported as Final Static import to the class file and can be used.
This way one can access the windows environment and use the espresso tests code wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the flavors. Add the flavor string in the BuildConfig and use it in your test cases. 

 This will be helpful http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing1

Comment: flavors are useful in different scenario, but not in my case. however, i found the solution to my problem and posted the answer above.